# Two fragments in one layout but only one is shown

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am working on an android project and I am trying to make use of fragments but I am having an issue.

In my fragment activity I have a layout which contains two fragments. For some reason when I load the activity, I am only seeing the first fragment which is the query editor.

Below is the layout for the fragment activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <fragment android:name="com.BoardiesITSolutions.MysqlManager.QueryEditor"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_queryEditor"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"/>
        <fragment android:name="com.BoardiesITSolutions.MysqlManager.ResultViewer"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_resultViewer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is the layout for the query editor fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#c1c1c1c1" >
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="QUERY EDITOR"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Below is the layout for the result view fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#000000">
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RESULT SET VIEW"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

For some reason only the query editor is being shown.

Although at the moment the query editor is set to 100dp and the result view is 300 dp I am only doing this as a test.

What I am actually wanting to do is to the query editor set to 100dp and the result view take up the rest of the space.

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<fragment android:name="com.BoardiesITSolutions.MysqlManager.QueryEditor"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_queryEditor"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>
    <fragment android:name="com.BoardiesITSolutions.MysqlManager.ResultViewer"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_resultViewer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />
```

with

```
 <fragment android:name="com.BoardiesITSolutions.MysqlManager.QueryEditor"
           android:id="@+id/fragment_queryEditor"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>
    <fragment android:name="com.BoardiesITSolutions.MysqlManager.ResultViewer"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_resultViewer"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />
```

this way your fragments will occupy the same space in the LinearLayout

Comment: That makes them side by side, I want the query editor at the top and the result view underneath, hence why the width was set to full and the height had to dp set

Comment: the the LinearLayout should be vertical, and also give width match_parent and height 0dip with weight 1.

Comment: Thanks, sorry didn't realise I had the orientation set the Horizontal thought I had changed it

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a `LinearLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout`?
This should do the thing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <fragment android:name="com.BoardiesITSolutions.MysqlManager.QueryEditor"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_queryEditor"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"/>
        <fragment android:name="com.BoardiesITSolutions.MysqlManager.ResultViewer"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_resultViewer"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_queryEditor"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I thought the linear layout may fix the issue. However, I've removed it now, but now the result viewer is being shown but the query editor fragment is not shown. Not sure why though